# C Double pointer Char is printing NULL. Don't Know what's going wrong?

Tags: c, double-pointer, char-pointer

This is display function to display the strings read in.

```
void print(char **s,int T)
{   

    while(*s)
    {

        printf("i: String : %s\n",*s++);

    }

}



int main()


{



int T =0,i=0;

    char ** s, *c;
    printf("Enter number of Testcases:\n");
    scanf("%d",&T);
    s = (char **)malloc(T*sizeof(char *));
    printf("Size allocated : %lu\n",sizeof(s));

    while(i++ < T)
    {
        s= (char *)malloc(10000*sizeof(char));
        scanf("%s",*s++);

    }
    print(s,T);


    return 0;
}
```

Comment: 1)`sizeof(s)` size of `char **`, not allocated size. 2) `s` rewrite by `s= (char *)malloc(10000*sizeof(char));` 3) `print(s,T);` : `s` is next of last or somewhere.

Comment: 4) `while(*s)` : It has not been secured extra for NULL.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This code:

```
s= (char *)malloc(10000*sizeof(char));
scanf("%s", *s++);
```

should be:

```
s[i-1] = malloc(10000);
scanf("%9999s", s[i-1];
```

I would advise to refactor the loop so that you use `i` within the loop rather than `i-1`.

Your original idea doesn't work because:

- you wrote `s` instead of `*s` in the `malloc`
- once this loop finishes, `s` points to the end of the list; but you then pass `s` to your print function which is expecting a pointer to the start of the list

Further, the `print` function currently iterates off the end of the array (if you pass `s` correctly as I suggest above, that is). Instead, it should stop after it has printed `T` strings. You should probably change the call to `print(s, i);` ; update `print` to loop based on that `int`, and also add a check for `scanf` failure.

Comment: I modified my code as you suggested. But still it behaves the same.

Comment: i=T;
 while(i > 0)
 {
  s[i-1]= (char *)malloc(10000*sizeof(char));
  scanf("%9999s",s[i-1]);
  
  printf("%s\n",s[i-1]);
  i++;
 }

Comment: The code you just posted in that comment writes off the end of the array. You want `i` to run from `0` to `T-1`, and access `s[i]`. Your code actually has `i` run from `T` to infinity.

Comment: The usual way to write a loop is `for (int i = 0; i < T; ++i)`

Answer (score 0):

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

void print(char **s,int T){
    int i=0;
    while(T--){
        printf("%d: String : %s\n", ++i, *s++);
    }
}

int main(){
    int T =0, i=0;
    char **s, **p;
    size_t size;

    printf("Enter number of Testcases:\n");
    scanf("%d",&T);
    p = s = (char **)malloc(size=T*sizeof(char *));
    //printf("Size allocated : %zu\n", size);
    printf("Size allocated : %lu\n", (unsigned long)size);

    while(i++ < T){
        char tmp[10000];
        scanf("%9999s", tmp);
        *p++ = strdup(tmp);//strdup is not standard function
    }
    print(s,T);
    //deallocate
    return 0;
}
```